# HTML/CSS: Keep Hovered Image in Menu Title While Hovered Over Submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a menu that has an image for its title, and changes images when it isn't hovered anymore. However, I want it to keep the same image while I'm hovering over the submenu that opens up beneath it, rather than revert back to its unhovered state. Can this be done with HTML/CSS?

Here's the CSS Code:

```css
ul#nav {
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
}

ul.drop a {
  display:block;
  color: transparent;
}

ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:  0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  color:      transparent
}

ul.drop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

ul.drop li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  zoom: 1;
}

ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.drop ul {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
}

ul.drop:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
ul.drop ul li {
  float: none;
}

ul.drop ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  left: 100%;
}

ul.drop li:hover &gt; ul {
  visibility: visible
}
```

And here's the HTML

```
<ul class='drop' id='nav' style='padding-bottom:8px;'>
  <li><img alt='Share' border='0' onmouseout='this.src=&apos;normal.png&apos;' onmouseover='this.src=&apos;hovered.png&apos;' src='normal.png' style='padding:0px; margin:0px;'/>
    <ul>
      <li style='background-color:#202020;width:160px;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>
         <!-- Share Buttons -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm.. i have a special trick for you, i hope you like it. I make HTML like this :

```
<ul id="nav" class="drop">
    <li class="icon1">HOVER ME
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#" onclick="alert('Iam clicked')">HIDDEN MENU</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="icon1">HOVER ME 2
        <ul>
            <li> HIDDEN MENU </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and special css trick like this:

```
...
    ul.drop li.icon1{
        background: url(YOUR_IMAGE) no-repeat left top;
        width: 140px;        
    }
   ul.drop li.icon1:hover{
        background: url(YOUR_IMAGE_HOVER) no-repeat left top;
    }
...
```

> Here the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/CsV7a/